# jQuery replaceWith(responseText) started encoding quotes as &quot; unexpectedly

Tags: html, jquery, encoding, double-quotes, replacewith

I'm encountering an issue where the jQuery `replaceWith(responseText)` function modifies the attribute values of elements by replacing double quotes with `&quot;`.

**Original responseText**:

```html
<div id='whatsapp_icon' onclick='whatsappClick("37112345678", "")'></div>
```

**After using replaceWith**:

```html
<div id="whatsapp_icon" onclick="whatsappClick(&quot;37112345678&quot;, &quot;&quot;)"></div>
```

This issue is recent, and previously the method worked as expected. Notably:

- The issue does not appear on all systems, but on most systems.
- I tried to disable all extensions in browsers, without result (and this behavior appeared not simultaneously, but during one or two days on completely independent systems).
- The code hasn't been modified recently.
- The jQuery library wasn't updated.
- The `.html()` function exhibits the same behavior.

What could be causing this change in behavior?

Comment: Are you sure this is caused by jquery? Have you inspected the responseText appropriately to ensure this isn't being caused by network or server security measures? jquery doesn't just start functioning differently.

Comment: Yes, the first thing I did was to output the responseText to the console (console.log(responseText)), there are normal quotes.

Actually I'm not sure if it's jquery and not, for example, the browser. This is indirectly indicated by the fact that it doesn't show up in the not-so-latest Chrome on Windows 8.1, but the effect is there in the latest Edge and Chrome on Windows 10.

But I couldn't google anything about it.

Comment: so you tested the responseText on a browser that was displaying it incorrectly? just to be sure we're getting the right results

Comment: If anything it's caused by a method jquery is using, after all, jquery is just using the dom api. so you should be able to rule out jquery by using .innerHTML, for example. but it's still good to first confirm 100% that the text you're passing to the insert method is the same in both working and not working browsers to rule out anything prior.

Comment: Yes, I check in the browser that has this issue and the responseText matches in both browsers. Thanks for the idea about innerHTML. I replaced the jQuery with this code `testText = "<div title='A \"TEST\" B'></div>"; var oldElement = document.getElementById('people_' + order_id); var parentElement = oldElement.parentElement; parentElement.innerHTML = testText;` The issue still persists, the quotes are replaced: `<div title="A &quot;TEST&quot; B"></div>` Where can I dig further?

Comment: And a small remark: if I put the quotes in a different order, they are not replaced by &quot: `testText = '<div title="A \'TEST\' B"></div>';`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes browser updates changes how HTML is being rendered and parsed. As you already mentioned the code hasn't been change neither the jQuery library nor the code. So a browser update might affect the way attribute values are displayed and processed.

Comment: I had the same thought, but it would mean that many sites would have to start functioning differently than before, and information about it would appear on the internet and here in particular. But I couldn't google anything about it. Perhaps it's still a bit of time that has passed, it only happened yesterday.